# Sorting January to December using group by month

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have written the query

```
SELECT 
    MONTHNAME( create_date ) AS MONTH, 
    COUNT( dollar_value_awarded ) AS monthly_sales_count 
FROM claims 
WHERE spiffid='$id' 
AND create_date BETWEEN '$sdate' AND '$edate' 
GROUP BY MONTH
```

and it displays

```
MONTH     monthly_sales_count
April       285
February    134
March       958
```

I want it to display like this:

```
MONTH     monthly_sales_count
February    134
March       958
April       285
```

that means the result should be sorted from January to December

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MONTHNAME( create_date ) AS month_name,             --- change this alias
       COUNT( dollar_value_awarded ) AS monthly_sales_count 
FROM claims 
WHERE spiffid = '$id' 
  AND create_date BETWEEN '$sdate' AND '$edate' 
GROUP BY MONTH(create_date)                         --- use the MONTH() function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pass in `MONTH(create_date)` as `ORDER BY` argument:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME( create_date ) AS MONTH , COUNT( dollar_value_awarded ) AS monthly_sales_count 
FROM claims WHERE spiffid='$id' and create_date 
BETWEEN '$sdate' AND '$edate' 
GROUP BY MONTH
ORDER BY MONTH(create_date)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,but it is not working,I am using mysql database and want to sort data from january to december

Comment: @Bulbul what hasn't worked? The data is not sorted or syntax error?

Comment: @NiftyDude: `ORDER BY MONTH` would alphabetically order the month names, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @beny23 um, no you are wrong. MONTH() is the function MONTH that gets the numeric representation out of a date... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Comment: @NiftyDude: Sorry, got myself confused, but does this actually work, as the `MONTH(create_date)` is not in the `GROUP BY` clause and the `ORDER BY` would have to be after the `GROUP BY`

Comment: shows syntax error,i have also changed order by month(create_date) to monthname(create_date),but still not working

Comment: @Bulbul let me create a schema and test thoroughly.

Comment: @Bulbul The record fetched shouldn't change as I was just copy pasting your originaly query and added the `order by`.. How wrong is the record?

Comment: it display MONTH  monthly_sales_count
              March  1
              April  8  instead of MONTH     monthly_sales_count
February    134
March       958
April       285

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
SELECT MONTHNAME( create_date ) AS MONTH, 
       COUNT( dollar_value_awarded ) AS monthly_sales_count 
  FROM claims 
 WHERE spiffid='$id' and create_date BETWEEN '$sdate' AND '$edate' 
 GROUP BY MONTH, MONTH(create_date)
 ORDER BY MONTH(create_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sinmply add an ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME( create_date ) AS MONTH , COUNT( dollar_value_awarded ) AS monthly_sales_count      
FROM claims 
WHERE   spiffid='$id' and create_date BETWEEN '$sdate' AND '$edate' 
GROUP BY MONTH 
ORDER BY MONTH(create_date)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need MONTH(create_date) in your GROUP BY clause, as per my answer?  Note, I've not tried this on MySQL only on Oracle with equivalent functions...

Comment: you can group by the alias in the 'AS' clause, which is MONTH, but GROUP BY MONTH(create_date) would work as well. This works with MySQL - I can't speak for oracle.

Comment: Interesting, if I don't put the (equivalent of) `MONTH(create_date)` in the `GROUP BY` clause in Oracle, it trips up with "not a GROUP BY expression"...

Comment: hi,i have tried but not working correctly.it fetching wrong record